# ffmpeg - Creates a Terminal like Text Video Instead of Slide Show Of Images

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg, rendering

I am using **ffmpeg** encoder to render Images in my Android App with the Help of this [Library](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java)

The following Command is used to Render video from a list of images.

```
String command[] = {"-r","1/5","-i",gpxfile.getAbsolutePath(),"-c:v","libx264","-vf","fps=25","-pix_fmt","yuv420p",root.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"video.mp4"};
```

and here the gpxfile is my text file that contains the following

```
    file '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/P_20170807_143916.jpg'
    duration 2
    file '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Pic/P_20170305_142948.jpg'
    duration 5
    file '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/P_20170305_142939.jpg'
    duration 6
    file '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Pic/P_20170305_142818.jpg'
    duration 2
```

My Problem is While Running the Command it renders a Terminal Like Black Screen with the TextPaths inside the file instead of a Video...!!!
 Any Suggestions...??

Here is my Project [Source Code](https://github.com/gotoark/SlideShowMaker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the Correct Command from [Deepak](https://github.com/gotoark/SlideShowMaker/issues/1).

```
String command[] = {"-y", "-f", "concat", "-safe", "0", "-i", gpxfile.getAbsolutePath(), "-vsync", "vfr", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", root.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"video.mp4"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your textfile to

```
file '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/P_20170807_143916.jpg'
duration 2
file '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Pic/P_20170305_142948.jpg'
duration 5
file '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/P_20170305_142939.jpg'
duration 6
file '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Pic/P_20170305_142818.jpg'
duration 2
file '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Pic/P_20170305_142818.jpg'
```

and then encode this command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i gpxfile.getAbsolutePath() -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p root.getAbsolutePath()/video.mp4
```

Comment: It throws this Error [concat @ 0xacb2e1d0] Unsafe file name '/storage/emulated/0/SlideShowMaker/SlideShowMaker Pictures/IMG-20171019-WA001-1-scale-1.jpg'
                                                                      /storage/emulated/0/SlideShowMaker/command.txt: Operation not permitted

Comment: Add `-safe 0` before `-i`